# Python timeit command-line error: "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal"

Tags: python, windows, command-line, cmd, timeit

I have been using the Python [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module for a long time, but it was only through an interactive Python session or a Unix shell. Now, I am trying to measure some code snippets in the Windows command prompt (*cmd.exe*), but it shows this error:

```
C:\Users\Me>python -m timeit '"-".join(map(str, range(100)))'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\runpy.py", line 160, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\runpy.py", line 73, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\timeit.py", line 334, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Python33\lib\timeit.py", line 298, in main
    t = Timer(stmt, setup, timer)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\timeit.py", line 131, in __init__
    code = compile(src, dummy_src_name, "exec")
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6
    '-.join(map(str,
                   ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

which is rather confusing, since I have not inserted any newline characters in the string - rather, I actually pasted the example directly from the timeit module documentation.

While playing around with this, I tried testing snippets without any spaces, since the error marked characters just before them. Even though no exception now occurs, the module reports the same execution time as if I had passed a `pass` statement, as shown here:

```
C:\Users\Me>python -m timeit
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.013 usec per loop

C:\Users\Me>python -m timeit 'map(str,range(100))'
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.013 usec per loop

C:\Users\Me>python -m timeit 'map(str,range(1000000000000000))'
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.013 usec per loop
```

I am sure I call the module correctly since I have pasted the same lines on a Unix shell and they work as expected.

Since I get the exact same results with Python 2.7 and 3.3 (plus, the module is written in pure Python and it has been around for a long time) I am sure that this has nothing to do with Python, but the Windows command prompt, instead.

So, why does this weird behaviour happen exactly and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 13):

## tl;dr

***Use double quotes for the statement passed to the timeit module.***
Example:

```
C:\Users\Me>python -m timeit "'-'.join(map(str, range(100)))"
10 loops, best of 3: 28.9 usec per loop
```

## Detailed explanation

In contrast to Unix shells such as *bash* and *tcsh*, single quotes are treated differently on a Windows command line.

Here is a tiny python program to demonstrate this:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1:])
```

Running this (let's call the file *cmdtest.py*), we observe the following:

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop>python cmdtest.py 1 2 3
['1', '2', '3']

C:\Users\Me\Desktop>python cmdtest.py "1 2 3"
['1 2 3']

C:\Users\Me\Desktop>python cmdtest.py '1 2 3'
["'1", '2', "3'"]
```

So, single quotes are treated literally (i.e. not as special characters). Searching a bit in SO, I found [this great description of argument tokenization by cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4094897/1751037):

> When invoking a command from a command window, tokenization of the
>   command line arguments is not done by `cmd.exe` (a.k.a. "the shell"). 
>   Most often the tokenization is done by the newly formed processes'
>   C/C++ runtime, but this is not necessarily so -- for example, if the
>   new process was not written in C/C++, or if the new process chooses to
>   ignore `argv` and process the raw commandline for itself (e.g. with
>   [GetCommandLine()][1]).  At the OS level, Windows passes command lines
>   untokenized as a single string to new processes.  This is in contrast
>   to most *nix shells, where the shell tokenizes arguments in a
>   consistent, predictable way before passing them to the newly formed
>   process.  All this means that you may experience wildly divergent
>   argument tokenization behavior across different programs on Windows,
>   as individual programs often take argument tokenization into their own
>   hands.
>
> If it sounds like anarchy, it kind of is.  However, since a large
>   number of Windows programs *do* utilize the Microsoft C/C++ runtime's
>   `argv`, it may be generally useful to understand how the MSVCRT
>   tokenizes arguments.  Here is an excerpt:
>
> - Arguments are delimited by white space, which is either a space or a tab.
> - A string surrounded by double quotation marks is interpreted as a single argument, regardless of white space contained within. A quoted
>     string can be embedded in an argument. Note that the caret (^) is not
>     recognized as an escape character or delimiter.

---

### Error #2

Having the above in mind, let's explain the second weird behaviour first (the one that acts as a `pass` statement), as it is a bit simpler. Since single quotes are interpreted literally, when calling:

```
C:\Users\Me>python -m timeit 'map(str,range(100))'
```

the exact string literal `'map(str,range(100))'` (with quotes included) is passed as the statement to time.
So, Python will see

```
"'map(str,range(100))'"
```

instead of

```
'map(str,range(100))'
```

which, as a string, doesn't really do anything and gives a measurement pretty close to a `pass` statement.

---

### Error #1

Now for the first error:
As it is documented for the python [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#command-line-interface) module:

> A multi-line statement may be given by specifying each line as a
>   separate statement argument;

So, when calling:

```
C:\Users\Me>python -m timeit '"-".join(map(str, range(100)))'
```

Python sees `["'-.join(map(str,", "range(100)))'"]` passed as statements to timeit, which the module interprets as the multi-line statement:

```
'"-".join(map(str,
range(100)))'
```

This has as its first line a string that opens with a single quote, but never closes, thus, (finally) explaining the bizarre EOL error.

---

## Solution

*Using double quotes for the statement to time solves the problem.*

I have also tried *Windows PowerShell*, which is more advanced than *cmd.exe* and exhibits similar behaviour with Unix shells, but didn't quite do the trick for all the statements that I tested.
For instance, this works (notice the space in the statement):

```
PS C:\Users\Me> python -m timeit 'map(str, range(100))'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.688 usec per loop
```

while the initial example doesn't:

```
PS C:\Users\Me\Desktop> python -m timeit '"-".join(map(str, range(100)))'
option -. not recognized
use -h/--help for command line help
```

(I am not yet really satisfied, though. What I would rather do is make *cmd* or *PowerShell* work as a Unix shell, so that I can simply paste and time code snippets. If anyone knows a quick-and-dirty way to do this (if it is even possible), in order to complete the answer, that would be awesome.)